# Ubuntu server terminal?

Tags: server, command-line, downloads

I installed ubuntu server on my windows 7 computer and can't reboot windows 7. I want know if I accidently formatted my hard drive or if I accidently replaced my OS. How do I download ubuntu from the ubuntu server terminal?

```
alejandro@JandroMunoz: ~$ df -h
Filesystem            Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/JandroMunoz-root
                      680G  1.4G  644G  1% /
undev                 3.9G  4.0K  3.9G  1% /dev
tmpfs                 1.6G  400K  1.6G  1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M  0% /run/lock
none                  3.9G  4.0K  3.9G  1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1             228M   29M  188M 14% /boot
/home/alejandro/.Private
                      680G  1.4G  644G  1% /home/alejandro
alejandro@JandroMunoz: ~$ mount
/dev/mapper/JandroMunoz-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
/home/alejandro/.Private on /home/alejandro type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=71839318eaf89afd,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=2aaae6
alejandro@JandroMunoz: ~$ sudo fdisk -l

[sudo] password for alejandro:

Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB,  750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00025c60

  Device Boot     Start         End     Blocks    Id  System
/dev/sda1  *       2048      499711     248832    83  Linux
/dev/sda2        501758  1465147391  732322817     5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5        501760  1465147391  732322816    8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/JanbroMunoz-root: 741.4 GB, 741360009216 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 90131 cylinders, total 1447968768 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/JandroMunoz-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
alejandro@JandroMunoz: ~$ sudo parted -l

Model: ATA TOSHIBA MK7559GS (scs1)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number   Start   End   Size   Type     File System  Flags
 1       1049kB  256MB 255MB  primary  ext2         boot
 2       257MB   750GB 750GB  extended
 5       257MB   750GB 750GB  logical               lvm

Error: /dev/mapper/JandroMunoz-swap_1: unrecognized disk label

Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/JandroMunoz-root: 741GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number   Start   End   Size   Type     File System  Flags
 1       0.00B   741GB 741GB  ext4
```

Comment: Are these two separate questions? How does, "*How do I download ubuntu from the ubuntu server terminal?*" relate to the rest of your question? Also, please run `df -h; mount; sudo fdisk -l; sudo parted -l` on the Ubuntu Server system and edit your question to include the text it tells you...*if* you are still booted into the Ubuntu Server system. Then shut down the Ubuntu server system with `sudo shutdown -P now`. (If you aren't still booted into it, don't boot back into it--instead, use a live CD to gather this information. This is in case you did overwrite your Windows system and documents.)

Comment: Please also see the considerations in the [Data Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) documentation, if it is at all possible that there were important documents in your Windows installation that were not backed up when you installed Ubuntu Server. (Whether or not your Windows system has been destroyed can be determined given the output of the command I provided in my previous comment, but if there's any possibility of loss of important data, you shouldn't use the *installed* Ubuntu Server system more than a few seconds longer than necessary, as that could cause more loss.)

Comment: I want to download ubuntu to check if my files are still there because I don't have my windows 7 disc to redownload onto my computer.

Comment: Are you still booted into your Ubuntu Server system? If so, please run `df -h; mount; sudo fdisk -l; sudo parted -l` and report the results (then shut down as explained above). If you had any important documents in Windows, then it's critically important that you do *not* create files in your Ubuntu Server system, as doing so is likely to overwrite the data and make those documents impossible to recover. Therefore, unless you have no important documents in the Windows system that are not backed up, you should *not* download an Ubuntu live CD .iso image in the installed Ubuntu Server system.

Comment: /dev/mapper/JanbroMunoz-root: 680G 1.4 G 644G 1% /: undev. 3.9G 4.0K 3.G 1%644G /dev: tmpfs 1.6G 400K 1.6G 1%400K /run: none 5.0M 0 5.0M 0%0 /run/lock: none 3.9G 4.0k 3.9G 1%4 /run/ahmed: /dev/sda1 228M 29M 188M 14% /boot

Comment: If you're sure you don't have important documents in your Windows system and are thus willing to greatly increase the chance your Windows files will be rendered completely unrecoverable, then you can use the nongraphical `links` web browser or the `wget` command to download the .iso image you want. For example, you could download the .iso for the 32-bit Ubuntu 11.10 desktop live CD with `wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso` and write it to a flash drive with `dd` burn it with `wodim`. (For help, see the [Ubuntu manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/) site.)

Comment: Says I don't have a valid partition table. And I do have files that I am hoping to be able to recover. I have to type this all with my phone, so it will take a while...

Comment: When you run `df -h; mount; sudo fdisk -l; sudo parted -l`, you should be getting more output even than your (edit) posted is showing. When you run that, you may be prompted for your password; as you enter it, you won't see any placeholder characters (like *). That's OK--just type it in and press enter. Also, please *edit your question* to include the output of that command. (In your question--not as a comment--you can enclose it in a **pre** block, i.e., between `<pre>` and `</pre>`, so that the formatting is preserved and it's not all scrunched into one line.)

Comment: It should not be saying you don't have a valid partition table, even if your Windows system *did* get overwritten. It would have been overwritten with the Ubuntu Server system, with all valid partition information. Can you provide all the output *in your question* by *editing your question* as requested?

Comment: Since, given what you have said, you may well have overwritten your Windows system when you installed Ubuntu Server, it is a bad thing to leave it booted for a very long time, because operations performed automatically by Ubuntu Server will progressively render more data unrecoverable and/or much more difficult to recover. Therefore, if you still have a ways to go in transcribing the output of that command into your phone, and you cannot simply take a picture of the screen and then immediately shut the system down, then you should just shut it down now and use a live CD.

Comment: Since your phone is probably not capable of downloading and writing a live CD .iso to a CD/DVD or USB flash drive, if you don't have another computer you'll have to do this with a friend's computer (or ask a friend to make you the flash drive or CD/DVD), or a public computer (for example at a library or Internet cafe). While a hassle, this is still a lot better than losing valuable documents permanently! (Plus, downloading and writing, or especially burning, a live CD .iso from the command line is also a hassle, when you are inexperienced with Ubuntu and under stress.)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The text from the command line that you have included does not show anything that looks like a Windows partition, so it is highly likely that you have installed Ubuntu Server to the entire disk, destroying your Windows system. While it is extremely unlikely that you could recover your Windows system, it may be possible for you to recover some important documents that it contained. You can follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) for doing so, starting with shutting down the system immediately (`sudo shutdown -P now`) if you have not done so already.

You'll need a live CD/DVD or live USB flash drive for this, but you should not attempt to create it on the current Ubuntu system, because (1) the longer you run the Ubuntu Server system, even if you are not doing much with it, the greater the risk of irreversible data loss from the contents of the old Windows partition, and (2) if you were to download a large file (like the Ubuntu desktop CD .iso image) on the system, that would be very likely to overwrite data that had belonged to files that were stored on the Windows system, very possibly including the important documents you wish to recover.

If those instructions don't enable you to recover your lost files, then you'll have to decide whether or not it's worth it to hire a data recovery specialist, which could cost thousands of dollars. You should probably not hire someone who is not a specialist for this purpose if [these methods](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) are not successful, because only a specialist is likely to be able to recover data not recoverable by those methods.

As for getting Windows back, you will need to reinstall it to achieve this. If your computer came with Windows but did not come with installation media (like a CD, DVD, or USB flash drive) then it is usually possible to order a Windows installation CD/DVD from your computer's manufacturer at relatively low cost (certainly much less than it would cost to buy another copy of Windows providing a new and separate license).